# How to use ANTLR4's BaseListener class to convert infix expression to postfix expression

Tags: java, antlr4, postfix-notation, infix-notation

So in ANTLR I have written grammar for infix expression and now I want to convert the infix expression input to postfix expression and then output the result to a text file.

Unless I am wrong, I believe this can be done in the BaseListener class which is generated by ANTLR but I am not sure how to make this conversion.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you require more info as well.

> ExpAnalyser.g4:

```
grammar ExpAnalyser;

// Parser/grammar    
//Infix Arithmetic

eval : additionExp ;

additionExp : multiplyExp(PLUS multiplyExp | MINUS multiplyExp)* ;

multiplyExp : unaryExp(MULT unaryExp | DIV unaryExp)* ;

unaryExp :  MINUS atomExp | atomExp ;

atomExp :  NUMBER | LPAREN eval RPAREN ;

// Tokenizers/Lexers
MULT  : '*' ;
DIV   : '/' ;
MOD   : 'mod' ;
PLUS  : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;
DOT   : '.' ;

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;

NUMBER : [0-9]+ ('e'[0-9]+)? ; 

COMMENT : '//' .+? ('\n'|EOF) -> skip ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

> ExpAnalyserBaseListener.java:

```
// Generated from ExpAnalyser.g4 by ANTLR 4.7.1

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ErrorNode;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;

/**
 * This class provides an empty implementation of {@link ExpAnalyserListener},
 * which can be extended to create a listener which only needs to handle a subset
 * of the available methods.
 */
public class ExpAnalyserBaseListener implements ExpAnalyserListener {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void enterEval(ExpAnalyserParser.EvalContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void exitEval(ExpAnalyserParser.EvalContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void enterAdditionExp(ExpAnalyserParser.AdditionExpContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void exitAdditionExp(ExpAnalyserParser.AdditionExpContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void enterMultiplyExp(ExpAnalyserParser.MultiplyExpContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void exitMultiplyExp(ExpAnalyserParser.MultiplyExpContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void enterUnaryExp(ExpAnalyserParser.UnaryExpContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void exitUnaryExp(ExpAnalyserParser.UnaryExpContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void enterAtomExp(ExpAnalyserParser.AtomExpContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void exitAtomExp(ExpAnalyserParser.AtomExpContext ctx) { }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) { }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation does nothing.</p>
     */
    @Override public void visitErrorNode(ErrorNode node) { }
}
```

Comment: Sure, this can be done after parsing in a visitor, listener, or some other way of traversing the parse tree. It is not really ANTLR related. Try searching Google for "infix to postfix" and you will find many results. There are also Q&A's here on SO about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699089/infix-to-postfix-using-stacks-java

Comment: Hmm... Could you maybe elaborate/give an example on how to parse using visitor or listener?

Comment: Sure, I recently posted examples of them both in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694645/antlr-4-how-to-handle-unary-negative-numbers